# How to fix screen margins on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution, screen, monitor

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an old computer I can't across. And when booting the computer on a spare monitor I had, the resolution got jacked up, and I to figure out how to remedy this. This is the first time I've seen this.

I've attached a picture below.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Picture of screen margins]

Comment: That's a hardware issue. Your monitor probably have an auto function to fix that

Comment: This^^^ but not really an hardware issue, more like a "feature". The point being this isn't a monitor but a TV that can be used as a monitor. As almost all TVs do what's shown in the picture is the effect of overscanning. Please read **your TV's** user's manual to find out how to change it. Be aware there's no standard. Some do it via menus, some have a dedicated key in the remote, etc.